# Ajax can't handle POST form submit, instead using default POST

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I do have form within a modal . What I'm trying to accomplish is to override the default POST method and use AJAX. I do it to prevent page switches. However it seems like script is not getting triggered. If I remove script normal POST occurs. Here is the code:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form action="process.php" method="POST" id="submitform">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="source">source:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="kaynak" name="kaynak" rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Kaydet</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submitform').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
            var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            var username = "<?php echo $username ?>";
            formData.push({
                name: 'username',
                value: username
            });

            $.ajax({
                    type: request_method,
                    url: post_url,
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    encode: true
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        })
```

Comment: `serialize()` returns a string.  Strings do not have a `push()` method

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.serializeArray()` not serialize since it returns a string and you want an array to add fields to it.

```
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var username = "<?php echo $username ?>";
        formData.push({
            name: 'username',
            value: username
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitform').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        var username = "<?php echo $username ?>";
        formData['name'] = username;
        $.ajax({
                type: request_method,
                url: post_url,
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                encode: true
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    })
```